# How to decode my json file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am new to Json file. I would like to ask a question regarding how to retrieve an single data from my json file like

```
"common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [75,0,0,0,242,57,95,229,91,72,205,100,56]
```

How could I get that single value from my json file?

Here is my Json File:

```
    {
     "result": {
     "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "",
     "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
     "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
      68,
      114,
      105
     ],
     "_datalogger": [
      {
        "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "_DataLogger",
        "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
        "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
          2,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          93,
          130,
          13,
          199
        ],
        "log_groups": [
          {
            "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Datalog",
            "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
            "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
              164,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              133,
              183,
              237,
              140,
              108
            ],
            "table_aliases": [
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "__internal",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
                "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
                  75,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  242,
                  57,
                  95,
                  229,
                  91,
                  72,
                  205,
                  100,
                  56
                ]
              }
            ],
            "triggers": [
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Trigger",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
                "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
                  109,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  85,
                  151,
                  173,
                  242
                ]
              }
            ],
            "log_items": [
               {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3         Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM01_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              },
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3    Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM02_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              },
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3 Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM04_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like the code in php

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. $array=json_decode($json,true); will put your json file into an associative array. from that point you should be able to do things like $array['results']["common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB"]. To print our array structure do var_dump($array);

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$var = '{
     "result": {
     "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "",
     "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
     "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
      68,
      114,
      105
     ],
     "_datalogger": [
      {
        "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "_DataLogger",
        "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
        "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
          2,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          93,
          130,
          13,
          199
        ],
        "log_groups": [
          {
            "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Datalog",
            "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
            "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
              164,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              133,
              183,
              237,
              140,
              108
            ],
            "table_aliases": [
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "__internal",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
                "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
                  75,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  242,
                  57,
                  95,
                  229,
                  91,
                  72,
                  205,
                  100,
                  56
                ]
              }
            ],
            "triggers": [
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Trigger",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
                "common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB": [
                  109,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  85,
                  151,
                  173,
                  242
                ]
              }
            ],
            "log_items": [
               {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3         Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM01_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              },
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3    Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM02_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              },
              {
                "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Scada 3 Channel.ScadaDevice1.WM04_Speed",
                "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$res = json_decode($var, true);
print_r( $res['result']['_datalogger'][0]['log_groups'][0]['table_aliases'][0]['common.ALLTYPES_HASHED_LEGACY_BLOB'][0] );
```

Comment: The question shows data from `table_aliases`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've updated the answer, but i did that one as an example.

Comment: Could you show me how to loop through all the data value in a tree level like an window explorer?

Comment: @elephant sorry, i didn't understand what you mean, could you explain more?